# AJAX request variable issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, callback, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery global variable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366113/jquery-global-variable-problem)

I'm doing a jQuery AJAX call and I want to save into a variable the response. However this variable is not having the value of the response outside of the AJAX call function. How can I get the response outside of the AJAX call function?

Example:

```
var responseText = '';
$.ajax({
    url: 'clients_handler.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'check_email', email: email },
    success: function(data) {
        responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
console.log(responseText);
```

So from my example `responseText` will be empty as set before the AJAX function.
How can i set this variable with the AJAX response value?

Comment: If I had £1 for every time this question gets asked...

Comment: You would be the richest man in all of wherever you're from!

Comment: Double if you count any synchronicity issue (calling event attachments before elements are in the DOM).

Comment: Log inside the success button, and then close your question.

Comment: This is a very popular question. Before you ask on SO, remember to use the search box (in the upper-right corner of the page) to see if someone's already asked the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that ajax fires asynchronously.  Essentially this means that you don't know when the ajax code will complete, so any lines of code *after* the call to `$.ajax` may execute before the `$.ajax` finishes (but not necessarily).  This is *why* callbacks for ajax are necessary.

One solution is to make the ajax request synchronous by using the `jQuery.ajax` option `async: false`, but this is probably not desired.

The true solution is to use the callbacks appropriately -- do all work you need to with `responseText` within the `success:` function.

Don't like having all of that code in one spot?  jQuery was nice enough to create Deferred and  have `jqxhr` implement it:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: url, data: data});
//thousands of lines of code here
$.when(jqxhr).done(function (responseText) { console.log(responseText); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save your variable the way you want because it is within a closure. 
The best you can do is to pass the response data to a function that will be executed after the request is done. Here's an example:

```
//code
$.ajax({
    url: 'clients_handler.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'check_email', email: email },
    success: function(data) {
        responseHandler(data);
    }
});


function responseHandler(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: This can also be written as `success: responseHandler`

Comment: yes, but he wants code outside the $.ajax, don't know why